# Hadoop: Path.getFileSystem vs FileSystem.get

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a Java class to create a HDFS directory, but want to check whether the directory exists before creating the directory. I'm not sure whether to use Path.getFileSystem() or FileSystem.get():

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path path = new Path(args[1]);
FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
if(fs.exists(path)) {
  System.err.println("Dir already exists");
  }
boolean status = fs.mkdirs(path);
```

Or should I use the FileSystem.get() method:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path path = new Path(args[1]);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
boolean status = fs.mkdirs(path);
if(!status) {
  System.err.println("Dir already exists");
  }
```

When is it appropriate to use either of these: Path.getFileSystem() or FileSystem.get()?

Comment: `FileSystem.get(conf);` - returns a filesystem based on configuration, static method; `path.getFileSystem(conf)` - filesystem based on default URI and a previously constructed Path, instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you already have a non-null `Path` object.

The null-safe approach would be to use a `Configuration` object with static method `FileSystem.get(conf)`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having multiple namespaces, then It is suggested to use **path.getFileSystem(conf)**;

**FileSystem.get(conf)** will always return the **default** Filesystem

**path.getFileSystem(conf)** will return the FileSystem with respect to path specified,

If it is a full path(eg. **hdfs://haservice2/dir1**) and the default namespace is **hdfs://haservice1**
**FileSystem.get(conf)** will return FS to **hdfs://haservice1**
and
**path.getFileSystem(conf)** will return the FS wrt path which is FS to **hdfs://haservice2/**, hence the FS calls for that path will succeed, which won't be the case if we used the FS from **FileSystem.get(conf)**

In case the path doesn't contains scheme & authority (eg. just /dir) the behaviour would be same for path.getFileSystem(conf) & FileSystem.get(conf). They both will return the Default FileSystem specified by **Fs.defaultFs** config.

Code wise, path.getFileSystem(conf) also calls FileSystem.get(..) only with the resolved URI.

```html
   * Return the FileSystem that owns this Path.
   *
   * @param conf the configuration to use when resolving the FileSystem
   * @return the FileSystem that owns this Path
   * @throws java.io.IOException thrown if there's an issue resolving the
   * FileSystem
   */
  public FileSystem getFileSystem(Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    return FileSystem.get(this.toUri(), conf);
  }
```